# how to make D3 ring chart combination of small circles connecting with lines

Tags: d3.js

Hi Can any one help me in creating a D3 chart in which i need to make a ring of many small circles and connect those small circles with lines.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far please?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it, given the following `nodes` and `links`

```
var nodes = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'];
var links = [{
    source: 10,
    target: 11
}, {
    source: 10,
    target: 1
}, {
    source: 10,
    target: 2
}, {
    source: 10,
    target: 3
}, {
    source: 10,
    target: 4
}, {
    source: 10,
    target: 5
}, {
    source: 10,
    target: 6
}, {
    source: 10,
    target: 9
}];

var pi = 3.14;
var r1 = 200;
var r2 = 20;
var height = 700;
var width = 700;
var cx = height / 2;
var cy = width / 2;
var delta = (2 * pi) / 12;

var circleGroup = d3.select('#svg').append('svg')
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('width', width)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + cx + ',' + cy + ')');

circleGroup.append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'big-circle')
    .attr('r', r1);

circleGroup.selectAll('.link')
    .data(links)
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .attr('x1', function(d) {
        return getX(nodes[d.source]);
    })
    .attr('y1', function(d) {
        return getY(nodes[d.source]);
    })
    .attr('x2', function(d) {
        return getX(nodes[d.target]);
    })
    .attr('y2', function(d) {
        return getY(nodes[d.target]);
    });

circleGroup.selectAll('.little-circle')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'little-circle')
    .attr('r', r2)
    .attr('cx', getX)
    .attr('cy', getY);

circleGroup.selectAll('.label')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append('text')
    .attr('class', 'label')
    .attr('x', getX)
    .attr('y', getY)
    .text(function(d) {
        return d;
    });

function getX(d) {
    var theta = +d * delta;
    return r1 * Math.cos(theta);
}

function getY(d) {
    var theta = +d * delta;
    return r1 * Math.sin(theta);
}
```

Here's a [working JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/6ab4bjqs/2/)

You're going to have to tweak how the nodes are added so you get can get the desired order :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what i was looking for.

Comment: @sandy great, could you please mark it as the answer, then?

Comment: Hi  Tejen Shrestha,can you also tell me how to put small circles on the lines please?

Comment: I've update the fiddle link with the addition of the small circles.